# Write UT for concurrent access of collections

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I have a **cache** like class, something like this:

```
class Cache {
   Map<String, Object> objects;
   Map<String, List<Object>> lists;
   //...
   List<Object> getFromLists(String key) {
   //...
   }

   Object getFromObjects(String key) {
   //...
   }

   void addObject(String key, Object value) {
   //...
   }
   //...
}
```

Now I am trying to write UTs to ensure the expected quality of the "cache" and I was wondering how to write them to ensure the structure works also when I have concurrent access. What I've tried so far, was to start multiple threads, some writing others reading and checking the content of the queue. I would appreciate other suggestions, maybe some tools?!

Comment: You can't test concurrency reliably, it's one thing that can be considered random. In order to write good, thread safe, code you need to have a thorough grounding in concurrent techniques, and rely almost solely on those. Tests may pass every time, but there might still be a 1 in 1,00,000 chance of catastrophic failure.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I had the same feeling, just thought to ask anyway! Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across [thread weaver](https://code.google.com/p/thread-weaver) the other days. It seems to be quite an elegant solution to testing concurrency scenarios, especially in the case I pointed in my question. The [user-guide](https://code.google.com/p/thread-weaver/wiki/UsersGuide) contains some examples that point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [JUnitPerf](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JUnitPerf.html). The library is designed to run a load test against your "unit" of work to increase the chances of hitting a concurrency issue.